# sqlite3 is chopping/cutting/truncating my text columns

Tags: sql, sqlite, truncate

I have values being cut off and would like to display the full values.

```
Sqlite3 -column -header locations.dbs "
select n.namelist, f.state, t.state
from names n
left join locations l on l.id = n.id
left join statenames f on f.st = l.st
left join statenames t on t.st = l.stto
where n.timing > 200601 and count(n.timing)<=15"
```

Which gives me

```
name        From State   To State  
----------  -----------  ----------
Jack        Connecticut  Louisiana 
Jeff Danie  New Hampshi  New Hampsh
```

The names are being truncated down to 10 characters or the length of the first row of data, whichever is longer. How can I stop this from happening without making the columns larger than they have to be?

Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a way to make it automatic, but you can use the `.width` command to manually specify the column widths.

See [here](https://www.sqlite.org/cli.html#changing_output_formats) (search the section for `.width`).

Comment: I know about .width and don't want to set these manually.  I guess sometimes the answer is just "Can't be done".  I'll probably start on a method to output to pipe deliminated, which won't truncate, and write another program to just expand that.

Comment: Well, it can't be done with sqlite, but it can be done. See zuloo's answer.

Comment: `.width` increases the column width but does no solve the problem with truncation

Answer (score 13):

you could just use column (the unix command) like this:

```
sqlite3 -list -separator "|" -header db.dbs "Select ...." | column -t -s "|"
```

`-list` and `-separator` can be omitted, as they are defaults

Comment: So the minimum call would be: `sqlite3 -header my.db "select * from my_table;" | column -t -s "|"`

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the [answer by zuloo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20447579/1916449), it is possible to use the interactive prompt and have automatic column widths too.

Apart from `column` you will also need [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) (`sudo apt-get install rlwrap` if you're on Ubuntu). You run it like this:

```
rlwrap -a -N -c -z pipeto sqlite3 -header locations.dbs
```

Or you can put an alias in your `.bashrc` or similar:

```
alias sqlite="rlwrap -a -N -c -z pipeto sqlite3 -header"
```

In the sqlite console, you can run your query like this:

```
select * from names; | column -n -t -s '|'
```

Or, to make it nicer, put a script somewhere in your `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
column -n -t -s '|'
```

Let's say it's called `pp`, don't forget to make it executable with `chmod u+x pp`. Then you can use the interactive prompt like this:

```
select * from names; | pp
```

Answer (score 0):

I was indeed looking for solutions for the exact same issue and I found this workaround:

```
sqliteresult=`sqlite3 -header -list $SQLITE_FILE "SELECT * ..." | tr "\\n" ";"`
sqliteresult="${sqliteresult/;/;-----------------------------;}"
sqliteresult="${sqliteresult//;/\n}"
sqliteresult="${sqliteresult//|/\t|\t}"
echo -e $sqliteresult
```

Hoping it helps :)

~Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to format several tables and show the rowid in a nice format.

```
#/usr/bin/env bash

cli_opts="-header"

for table in "table1" "table2"; do
    select="select rowid as ' ', * from $table;"
    #echo "$select"
    echo "$table"
    sqlite3 $cli_opts database.db "$select" | column -t -s "|"
    echo -e '\n'
done
```